# Variable of type enum is not a type name?

Tags: c++

When running the following code, I recieve an error saying "shape" is not a type name.  Can anyone help?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

enum triangleType {scalene, isosceles, equilateral, noTriangle};        //Define an enumeration of possible triangle types  
triangleType shape;

shape triangleShape(int a, int b, int c);    //Declare prototype for function that calculates triangle type and returns enumeration

int main()
{      
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `shape` is a variable whose type is `triangleType`, it's not a type name.

Comment: Ahh I see.  What should the function return then? triangleType?

Comment: Yes, that's the type name.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should fix your problem with the error messages:

```
enum triangleType {scalene, isosceles, equilateral, noTriangle};
// triangleType shape; // shape here is a declared variable of type triangleType.

// triangleType is the type which is an enumerated type or integral type so this is valid.
triangleType triangleShape(int a, int b, int c);   
// having a function to return a variable and not a type will generate an error
// shape triangleShape( int a, int b, int c ); // error - shape is not declared as type.

int main()
{      
    return 0;
}
```